# Can be Rubin's pooling method (multiple imputation) be combined with Kenward-Roger or Satterthwaite degrees of freedom?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multiple-imputation, generalized-least-squares

I would like to use multiple imputation algorithm with a Generalized Least Square with Kenward-Roger or Satterthwaite degrees of freedom. Does the commonly implemented Rubin's method account for those complicated methods of calculating degrees of freedom? Can you provide any reference?